# VBA - sum totals to a master worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, function, sum

Okay, so here goes. I have a workbook with individual worksheets for each day detailing the stock trading activity. I also currently have a VBA which provides a sum total for specified columns on each of these worksheets, and this works fine.

However, what I would like to do is add to my VBA so that it provides a sum total for these columns into the master worksheet.

So, for example: If there was trading activity totalling 4m on the 1st Oct 2018 on worksheet 1, and trading activity totalling 3m on 2nd october 2018 on worksheet 2, I would like to have this total of 7m shown on the master worksheet.

I've attached my current vba below, the column currently being summed on each individual worksheet is J. The columns summed on the individual worksheet do not change, however the amount of data contained in those columns obviously does depending on trading activity.

```
Sub autoSum_AllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel1 As String, cel2 As String
    Dim firstCel As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            Set firstCel = .Range("J3").End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0)
            cel1 = firstCel.Offset(-2, 0).End(xlUp).Address
            cel2 = firstCel.Offset(-1).Address
            firstCel.Value = "=SUM(" & cel1 & ":" & cel2 & ")"
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I've also attached a screenshot of a current mock worksheet taken from a random day, with the sum total i get after running the vba bolded and highlighted in red.

[image: VBA]

Any advice on how to approach this would be great as I'm a newcomer to all things VBA.

**Edit: I've attached a mock screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve on the master worksheet below:**

[image: master worksheet example of what i need]

Comment: Is your code working so far or not? What *exactly* is the issue? Any errors? What is your question? You didn't ask one.

Comment: The code is working, what I would like to do is find out if there is a way to have the current sum total it produces on the individual worksheets also moved onto a master worksheet. So for example, if I go back to look at the data for week 39 (1st-5th october) I could find the sum total from the individual worksheets on a master worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the following …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AutoSumAllWorkheets()
    Const MasterName As String = "Master" 'specify name of master sheet

    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next 'test if master exists
    Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(MasterName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wsMaster Is Nothing Then 'add master if not exists
        Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1))
        wsMaster.Name = MasterName
        'instead you can throw a message and exit here
        'MsgBox "No master found"
        'Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim FirstCell As Range, LastCell As Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Name <> MasterName Then 'don't sum on master sheet
                Set FirstCell = .Range("J3")
                Set LastCell = FirstCell.End(xlDown)
                LastCell.Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=SUM(" & FirstCell.Address & ":" & LastCell.Address & ")"

                'write in master
                With wsMaster.Cells(wsMaster.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
                    .Offset(1, 0).Value = ws.Name
                    .Offset(1, 1).Formula = "=" & LastCell.Offset(2, 0).Address(External:=True)
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

    'sum all sheets up
    With wsMaster.Cells(wsMaster.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        .Offset(2, 0).Value = "Total sum:"
        .Offset(2, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & wsMaster.Cells(1, "B").Address & ":" & .Offset(0, 1).Address & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```

The first part checks if a master sheet exists and adds one if it doesn't exist.

Then I improved your code a bit:

- I recommend to use clear variable names (makes it easier). For example your `firstCel` actually was not the first but the sum cell. That is very confusing and you will easily fail.
- Use `.Formula` to write a formula.
- I added some code to write the sums of each sheet into the master sheet. Note that this appends the entries at the master sheet. So if you run it twice you need to clear the entries in the master sheet first.

If you want to write into another column of the master sheet just change the column name of `wsMaster.Cells(wsMaster.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)` from `"A"` to eg `"L"`

Comment: Thank you, i've tried your code and it creates a new worksheet titled master and adds a figure to it. However it has now stopped including the sum totals on the individual worksheets, is there a way to still keep these as well? Additionally, is there a way to add the date to column a on the master worksheet once it does the VBA is run and it does the calculation?

Comment: this still creates the sum on each individual worksheet in column J and sums from J3 to last used cell. Debug your code (go through it step by step using F8) to see what happens in each step.

Comment: my mistake, you're right the code you've suggested works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub test4()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRowJ As Long
Dim MasterTotal As Double

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    LastRowJ = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    MasterTotal = MasterTotal + ws.Range("J" & LastRowJ).Value '<= Let us assume that total appears in each sheet at the last line in column J
Next ws

Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = MasterTotal '<= Change where you want to import the total of totals

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I should probably add I already have a master worksheet (I've edited my post with a screenshot of it) which contains other data on it. Is there anyway to specify the column where I would like the data to appear? So for example, would it be possible through the VBA so that in column F I can have a cell which shows the date range (1st-5th Oct for example) and in the adjacent cell in column J it shows the sum values for those dates? My screenshot will try to demonstrate this